# Reuse component template angular 7

Tags: angular, angular7

Is there any simple way to reuse a template from a component 1 in a component 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible ways ideas:

1. Use component1 just as child component inside component2 element.
2. Create template, and use it with ng-template inside component 1 anx component2 temllates.
3. In component2 decorator just specify component1 template file.

Comment: But i can't  use component1 just as child component1 inside component2. 
My components are independent

Comment: Component2 template file:  <comp1></comp1>

Comment: Thanks you. it's simplae way.